# Opencv Android ndk r14b+ and clang/libc++

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I try to integrate opencv in another C++ code compiled with clang/libc++.

By default opencv is compiled by g++/gnustl, so I got issues with undefine symbol (like `_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev`) due to clang/libc++ differences.

Is there a method to compile opencv with ndk r14b and clang/libc++ ?

Opencv officially don't support ndk newer than r10 and all answers we can find are not update since 2 years.

*Edit: reformulation*

Comment: OpenCV relies on gnustl. You should use the same for your APP_STL.

Comment: @AlexCohn: should probably leave that as an answer so it can be marked correct :)

Comment: You can compile OpenCV with r14, but it would probably be much easier to use gnustl as APP_STL